# How can I tell if a field has changed value in an AT object in plone?

Tags: python, plone, zope, archetypes

I have an AT content type in Plone. It has a number of fields, including a file field. When the user edits an object of this type, how can I tell if a new file was uploaded?

For that matter, how can I tell if any of the fields have been changed?

I am currently using subscribers to hook into the IObjectEditedEvent to do some after the object changes - can I do these things here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `IObjectEditedEvent` (a direct subclass of `IObjectModifiedEvent`) is emitted when an Archetypes content object is being changed.

However, the event itself will not tell you if a new file was uploaded. It should be possible however, to obtain the request (context.REQUEST should give you the current request through acquisition, for example) and see if there is a file object there matching the field. If so, the user uploaded a new file for that field and the `FileField` will have been updated.

Comment: Thanks; I used 
request = zope.app.component.hooks.getSite().REQUEST 
instead of context, then checked 
request.has_key('FileField_file')
which only seems to appear if FilField has been updated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I tied to the IObjectEditedEvent:

Using the default form created from subclassing ATBlob, 
implementing (IATBlobFile, IATFile, IFileContent)

```
def editObjectEvent(context, event):
    status = context.REQUEST.form.get('file_delete')
    if status in ("nochange", NONE):
        print "Don't do anything, no change to file."
    else:
        print "Do something, the file has changed"
```

I'd like to know what other values `form['file_delete']` can have.  It seems useful.